# different result for xpath as a function and xpath at table creation

Tags: xml, xpath, hive

I have an xml file. The structure is

```
<ROW>
.....
<COLUMN NAME="CNAL"><![CDATA[R]]></COLUMN>
<COLUMN NAME="ID_STATUS"><![CDATA[9]]></COLUMN>
.....
</ROW>
```

When I try parsing this row with a function

```
select xpath(row, '/ROW/COLUMN[@NAME="ID_STATUS"]/text()');
```

I get

```
9
```

But when I try the same path at table creation

```
create external table db.table(
...
, id_status string
...
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
...
  , "column.xpath.id_status"='/ROW/COLUMN[@NAME="ID_STATUS"]/text()'
...
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location '/storage/db/db/table'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "xmlinput.start"="<ROW",
  "xmlinput.end"="</ROW>"
);
```

And then select, I get

```
<![CDATA[9]]>
```

Why is that, and what exactly is `<![CDATA[]]>`? How would I get rid of it during `create`?
The xml was exported from orale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDATA is a way of writing text content in which the characters & and <, which normally have a special meaning, are to be interpreted as representing themselves. If you wrap a string like '9' or 'N' (that has no special characters) in a CDATA section, then the CDATA section is pointless, but still allowed.

The XPath rules say that `<x><![CDATA[NNN]]></x>` is exactly equivalent (after parsing) to `<x>NNN</x>`. The CDATA tags shouldn't affect the result of the XPath expression. But not all specs in the XML family agree: some, like DOM, retain a distinction between the two cases even after parsing.

Now, so long as the XPath expression selects the node in both cases, it's not actually wrong for the software displaying the results of the XPath expression to display the node in different ways for the two cases. The fact that XPath can't distinguish them doesn't mean that no-one else can. And in your case, the difference isn't in which nodes were selected, it's in how they are displayed afterwards.